# First return value of function undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, console.log

So I have a function here that returns an element of an array for every function call. It keeps from returning the same element twice by checking against another array that used elements are pushed to.

The problem is that I keep getting "undefined" back when I run it the first time. If I make more than one console.log call, the calls after the first one return an element.

I'm thinking it has to do with my first "if" statement, but I'm not sure. Does an empty array return a length property of 0? Is that the issue in my "if" statement?

I appreciate all the help, thanks in advance.

```
var fortunesList = [
  "A",
  "B",
  "C",
  "D",
];

  var usedFortunes = [];


var getFortune = fortunesList[Math.floor(Math.random()*fortunesList.length)];

function fortuneCookieGenerator(getFortune) {
  if (usedFortunes.length == 0) {
    usedFortunes.push(getFortune);
  }   
  else if (usedFortunes.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < usedFortunes.length; ++i) {
      if (usedFortunes[i] == getFortune) {
        getFortune = fortunesList[Math.floor(Math.random()*fortunesList.length)];
        i = 0;
      }  
    }
    usedFortunes.push(getFortune);
  }
  return getFortune;
}


console.log(fortuneCookieGenerator());
console.log(fortuneCookieGenerator());
console.log(fortuneCookieGenerator());
console.log(fortuneCookieGenerator());
```

Comment: Syntax error `,` extra comma.

Comment: You forget getFortune in your calls : console.log(fortuneCookieGenerator(getFortune));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getFortune` is undefined because you have that as an argument to `fortuneCookieGenerator` but you pass in nothing. After the first time your function gets called `usedFortunes.length` is greater than 0 triggering the else branch and you assign a new value to `getFortune` and return that.

You might also benefit from these JS debugging guides: [Creativebloq](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger), [Google](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: This fixed the undefined problem, but now elements from the fortunesList array repeat themselves again, any idea why this is?

Comment: Nvm, I fixed this by setting i = -1 in the if block that's in the else if block. Oh, and thanks for the links, will take a look at those.

Answer (score 1):

Your function has the next signature

```
function fortuneCookieGenerator(getFortune)
```

which means that you can pass an argument, `getFortune` to it. Now, when you want to call the above function, you use the next;

```
fortuneCookieGenerator()
```

Which means that you're calling the function without passing an argument. So, at the first call, the `getFortune` is not defined yet. Also, the variable `usedFortunes` is still empty. As result of this,

```
usedFortunes.push(getFortune);
```

from the first `if` block gets invoked. You're pushing an undefined variable to the array. Once that gets done, the program proceeds to

```
return getFortune;
```

Which returns `undefined`.

At the second call, you still don't pass an argument, but the variable `usedFortunes` now is not empty. So it will execute the `else if` block. There, you have

```
getFortune = fortunesList[Math.floor(Math.random()*fortunesList.length)];
```

which initializes the variable. As result of this,

```
return getFortune;
```

holds something, you don't receive `undefined` anymore. That's why you are getting `undefined` at first call, but not at second and further calls.

Comment: Hey Karel, this was a great break down. I wish I could give you best answer also, but since I understood the issue in my code after reading the first answer, I awarded it to that first answer by default. Thanks again tho!

Answer (score 0):

getFortune() will be undefined if the condition is not true, so I think you need to add else part also to intialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Do this at first:

```
console.log(fortuneCookieGenerator(getFortune));
```

Or,

```
function fortuneCookieGenarator(getFortune){
.......
```